# How to use mongoose validation with update()

Tags: mongodb, validation, express, mongoose, schema

I have schema where I have field,which type is a number.I set min 0 but after updating its changing into negative number.So here is my schema.

```
let balanceChecker = (v)=>{
    if(v<0){
        return v=0;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
} 

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  email: {type: String,required: true,unique:true},
  password: {type: String,required: true,unique:true,validate: passwordValidators},
  coins:{type:SchemaTypes.Double,default:1000,min:0,required:balanceChecker}
});
```

After every click my app generating random number from -50 to 50. min:0 and required function not works.Here is my function which interact with DB.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({email:email},{coins},(err,success)=>{
                if(err) return err;
                nsp.in(room).emit('takeCoin', { coins });
            });
```

I need to add functionality that will change coins to zero when coins numbers will be negative value.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the code below will work or not but the algorithm should be correct.
So you have to use `pre` method.

```
   UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if (user.coins < 0) {
        user.coins = 0;
        next();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

The code should be in your model.